# How to overlay text out from div

Tags: html, css

Here I have 3 div containers in which `.div1` contains the text on each line. The text which has more words is wrapping onto next line and getting chopped off.

What I want to do is have all the text on each line to be in one single line.

i.e text can overlap on the neighbor div but without increasing the width of the `.div1`.

How can I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.div1{
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    background:orange;
    float:left;
}

.div2{
    width:60%;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    float:left;
}

.div3{
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    background:skyblue;
    float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="div1">
dksjdlkaslasf<br>
sdlkasdlaskjdksadjlad<br>
dlkasdlksajdlksajdlglkajf fjaflksajflkasjfa<br>
scahsnsa cnaskd asbjsanfsaa fm,sanflsafksajflasfnlkfjlksamflkajlfnsalkhflksafnaslhflasf</br>
</div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding z-index.

```
.div1{
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    background:orange;
    float:left;
    z-index: 10;
    position:relative; //(z-index only works on positioned elements)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add position:absolute

```
 .div1{
width:20%;
height:100%;
background:orange;
float:left;
position:absolute;
}
```